# How do I render a partial asynchronously/using AJAX in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, asynchronous

I currently have the following code to load a partial when I scroll to the bottom of a div with a table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pastGigs").scroll(function () {
            if (isScrollBottom()) {
                $('#pastGigs tr:last').after('<%= render "layouts/pastGigs" %>');

                $(this).unbind("scroll");
            }
        });

        function isScrollBottom() {

            var elementHeight = $("#pastGigs")[0].scrollHeight;
            var scrollPosition = $("#pastGigs").height() + $("#pastGigs").scrollTop();
            return (elementHeight == scrollPosition);
        };

    });
```

It works fine, but the reason I'm using the partial is because I don't want everything to load immediately, as it really slows the page down. Should I not be using a partial at all, or is there another way to execute the script and load the content only after scrolling? I've had a look around similar questions on stackoverflow, they all explain how to render the partial (I didn't know about escape_javascript and deleted all whitespace in the partial manually...), but none seem to solve my current speed issue. There is a difference of about 15 seconds (!) due to the amount of data in the partial, which is why I don't want to load it synchronously.

EDIT: Current config/routes.rb:

```
root "resnate_pages#home"
resources :users, :path => ''
```

EDIT 2: Current error in Terminal:

```
Processing by UsersController#show as */*
Parameters: {"id"=>"pastGigs"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "pastGigs"]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=pastGigs):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:5:in `show'
```

Comment: Two questions: #1 unless I've overlooked something I don't see any Ajax anywhere. If you examine your rendered JS in the browser, you'll probably see a huge blob of HTML text in the `.after` function; in other words, that partial is rendered immediately. #2 what is the problem you're having (why are you concerned about whether to use a partial)?

Comment: The code is supposed to use the Songkick API to bring back a user's past gigs, along with images and setlists. If you go back 20 or so gigs... that's a lot of data to load all at once, so I'm limiting it to 2 on initial load and wanting to load the rest when scrolling to the bottom of a div. I just tried changing $(document).ready to $(window).bind("load", but it doesn't make any speed difference. I guess my main problem is I've misunderstood AJAX?

Comment: Also, there's no HTML dump after the .after function when I view source code in my browser, none of the data that will load after scrolling appears there.

Comment: No wait, you're right, I'm wrong, I see the huge dump of text now. I guess that's because it's rendering the partial immediately, hadn't thought of that :P I guess I should be loading a separate page instead of using a partial?

Comment: Nope you're fine with the partial. I'll respond better in a minute after I've better examined your code and responses (in transit at the moment).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it :) Currently looking at jquery.ajax API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking over everything, it looks like you have the right idea with rendering the partial except that, as we discussed, it is not actually being loaded asynchronously. Since you have the ERB tags in the body of the javascript, the ERB is actually being rendered server-side before being delivered to the browser (as you noticed, with the huge blob of HTML text). The reason this appeared to work (meaning avoiding the huge 15-second load times you mentioned) is because the HTML text isn't actually interpreted as HTML yet by the browser when the page loads (its just a plain 'ol string at this point). It will of course be parsed and evaluated when you do add it to the DOM with the `.after` function.

So basically we just need to ajax this stuff up. Good that you're looking at the jQuery ajax documentation; definitely worth the time and its pretty informative. There is also a [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function which you might want to see as well. Its a convenience method for sending a `GET` request; you have less control, but if that doesn't matter, it can help keep things clean. I'll demonstrate with the `$.get` function, and you can choose to use the `$.ajax` function instead if you need the control (or prefer the other).

Put this in your `scroll` function:

```
$("#pastGigs").scroll(function () {
    if (isScrollBottom()) {

        $.get("/pastGigs", function(result){
            $('#pastGigs tr:last').after(result);
        });

        $(this).unbind("scroll");
    }
});
```

You can name the `pastGigs` route however you like, its only for demonstration purposes. Ensure you set up the route in your `routes.rb`

```
get "/pastGigs" => "users#pastGigs"
```

OR

```
get "/pastGigs", to: "users#pastGigs"
```

Again, I don't know what your controller is called, so replace it and the action name with the correct ones in your system.

And finally, the controller action:

```
def pastGigs
   render :partial => "layouts/pastGigs"
   # OR
   # render "layouts/pastGigs", :layout => false
end
```

The end result will be that when the scroll reaches the bottom, an ajax call is fired off to that URL and your partial is rendered and returned to the success function (the second parameter of `$.get`). The `result` variable will contain the rendered HTML partial.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Not sure I follow, why is it $.get("pastGigs/" and not $.get("/pastGigs" or $.get("#pastGigs ? I'm currently using the root directory so I've set the route to "root#pastGigs". Currently getting errors in terminal when I scroll to bottom of div, so I know the scroll is working as before, will troubleshoot a bit more.

EDIT: Also, the page I'm routing from is a partial, so do I need to include that in the route?

Comment: OK, the main error is because it's from a user page (though the user page routes to root), it keeps trying find a user with an id of "pastGigs". I've tried adding the controller action to UsersController but that doesn't work and doesn't seem like it should anyway. Should the initial $.get be looking for a different route?

Comment: @user2445163 What's the error you're getting in the console? Regarding the exact route, yes I made a mistake, my example should be `/pastgigs`. However, I'm not sure what you mean by the "root" directory. Remember that every request to your system, even in a simple case of rendering a partial, must go through a controller. There's no such thing as directories in the conventional (PHP-like?) sense. If you have a controller called `RootController` for example, then the route you mentioned should work. If not, maybe stick the `pastGigs` action in the same controller that rendered this page.

Comment: @user2445163 Ok, I think I know what is happening. Can edit the question and post the relevant part of your `routes.rb` (the update you made plus the user portion you mentioned - I need to see how you wrote it to see what its doing)? Or if its not too large, just post the whole thing.

Comment: So it should go through the UsersController, I suppose? Will edit original question now.

Comment: @user2445163 Yes, I think it would be simpler if our `def pastGigs` action was in `UsersController`. So, looking at the routes file you posted, I don't see where you added the `get "/pastgigs"` line I mentioned. If you add that **above** the `resources :users`, does it work as intended?

Comment: Moving the route get "pastGigs" => "users#pastGigs" above resources :users and changing the layout name from _pastGigs to pastGigs seems to be moving along the right track. I got nilClass errors because it didn't recognise @user in the partial page, so I set "@user" to current_user. It then loaded the data, but added the rest of the application layout (i.e. navbars etc.). I got around this problem on a different page before with render :layout => :false but I get a DoubleRender error if I attempt that now, how do I prevent it from adding the rest of the layout?

Comment: OK, had a look around, final UsersController code is "render "layouts/pastGigs", :layout => false". Thanks for all your help, will edit your answer to include additional code.

Comment: @user2445163 You might have to do `render :partial => "layouts/pastGigs"`. I thought it would do a partial by default, but maybe not.

Comment: Yeah, I had to get rid of underscore in filename, no worries, it's all working now!

Answer (score 1):

Quickly adapted Paul's code to populate a modal for anyone who's interested:

```
$('#seeAll').click(function(){
$.get("/pastGigs", function(result){
$('#pastGigsBody').html(result);});
});
```

When the user clicks on "See All" in the Past Gigs div, it opens the modal with the all of the past gigs. Thanks to Paul for teaching me about the $.get request.